# How can I avoid hardcoding a file path?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using RStudio to knit an `.Rnw` file to .`pdf`. This `.Rnw` file is stored in directory that is under git version control. This directory also contains a `.RProj` file for the project.

I collaborate with colleagues who don't know the first thing about `.Rnw` files and git. These colleagues want to open a Word file and track change their hearts out. So I give the people what they want.

Everyone needs access, so storing the Word file on a cloud service like Box makes sense. In the past I created a subfolder in my repo that I shared—keeping everything within the root directory—but this time around I needed to store the file in a shared folder that someone else created. So my solution was to copy the Word file from this shared directory to my repository.

**Technical Approach**

I don't know how to make this a reproducible problem, but hopefully you will give me some latitude since I'm trying to make my work fully reproducible ;)

Let's say that my `.Rnw` file is stored in `repoRoot/subfolder`. Since `knitr` changes the working directory to `subfolder` where this `.Rnw` file is located, the first chunk sets the `root.dir` one level up at the project root.

```
<<knitr, include=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../')) # go up 1 level
@
```

The next chunk copies the Word file from the shared folder to my git repo and runs the analysis file. *The shared directory path is hard coded to my machine, which is the problem I'm writing for your help solving.*

```
file.copy(from='/Users/ericpgreen/Box Sync/Project/Paper/draft.docx',
          to='subfolder/draft.docx',  # my repo
          overwrite=TRUE)
source(scripts/analysis.R)  # generates objects we reference in the .docx file
```

After adding `\begin{document}`, I include a chunk where I convert the `.docx` file to `.txt` and then rename it to `.Rnw`.

```
# convert docx to txt
  system("textutil -convert txt 'subfolder/draft.docx'")
# rename txt to .Rnw
  file.rename('subfolder/draft.txt', 
              'subfolder/draft.Rnw')
```

The next child chunk calls this `.Rnw` file that contains the text of the Word file with references to R objects included through `\Sexpr{}`:

```
<<include-draft, child='draft.Rnw', include=FALSE>>=
@
```

This works just fine for me. Whenever I knit the `.Rnw` file it grabs the latest version of the `.docx` file that my colleagues have edited (complete with track changes and comments) and, in a later step not shown here, returns the `.pdf` file to the shared folder.

**Problem to Solve**

This setup meets almost every need for me, except that the initial `file.copy()` command is hard coded to my machine. So if someone in my group clones my repo (e.g., research assistants who DO use version control), it won't run out of the box. Is there a workaround to hard coding in this type of case?

Comment: use `tempdir()` and `tempfile()` and ask the users to copy contents from the temporary directory. If you want a specific directory to be your temporary directory, `tmpdir` argument in `tempfile()` allows you to control the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you won’t get around hard-coding paths that are outside your control, such as paths to network shares. What you *can* and *should* avoid is hard-coding these paths in your documents.

Instead, relegate them to configuration files and/or environment variables (which, again, will be controlle by configuration files, to with `.bashrc` and similar). The simplest approach is then to use

```
network_share_path = Sys.getenv('NETWORK_SHARE_PATH',
                                stop('no network share path configured'))
file.copy(from = network_share_path, to = 'subfolder/draft.docx', overwrite = TRUE)
```